# Let apache follow the SVN authentication

Tags: apache, http, svn, authentication, webdav

I'm currently running three repositories with svnserve, all in `/var/svn`, all with a different passwd file (used by subversion, so /var/svn/the-repo/conf/passwd) of course. I'm also using apache with the DAV SVN module, like this:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
        ServerName svn.my-server.com
        ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/svn.my-server.com/error_log
        CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/svn.my-server.com/access_log combined
        <Location />
                DAV svn
                SVNParentPath /var/svn/
                SVNListParentPath On
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is working perfectly. However, when I browse to http://svn.myserver.com/repo-1, I am not asked for authentication: I'm able to view everything without providing credentials.

I know how to make apache ask me for credentials using HTTP authentication. But what I would like, is to have apache use the same authentication as svnserve. Is this possible?

Later, I might add new repositories. I would like that I don't have to configure apache again, then.

---

<sup>I suppose it doesn't change anything, but I'm using nginx as a proxy to apache.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know how to make apache ask me for credentials using HTTP
>   authentication. But what I would like, is to have apache use the same
>   authentication as svnserve. Is this possible?

Nope, it is not. You have to configure authentication in Apache separately. See [SVNBook | httpd, the Apache HTTP Server | Authentication Options](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authn).

> Later, I might add other repositories to the same directory /var/svn.
>   I would like that I don't have to configure apache again, then.

Since you say that you gonna add repos in future, you can stay with `SVNParentPath` but you have to use only one htpasswd file for all of your repos.

Comment: I'm sorry for the unclarity, but the different passwd files I was talking about are the passwd files used by subversion, in the-repo/conf/passwd, _not_ htpasswd files as could be used by apache's basic authentication.

Comment: @CamilStaps aw, my bad. I misunderstood this part. Then the answer would be just "no, you can't".

Comment: @CamilStaps what's the use case to expose your repos via svnserve and httpd at the same time?

Comment: I want to allow users to browse the repositories in their browser to allow them to view the repo on a computer where there is no SVN client installed. In the past, I only used the SVN protocol, so all users have configured it with this, and I don't want them to have to change.

Comment: In that case you could just drop svnserve and have the clients use http as well.

Comment: @CamilStaps you can continue using `svnserve` for Subversion client access and install web interface (WebSVN, FishEye, ViewVC, Sventon) on Apache HTTP Server so your users could view repos contents using a web browser.

Comment: _Ah_, I was not aware of the existence of a web interface, and didn't think of that. Thank you very much!